# Possible to copy a line of code during error handling?

Tags: excel, vba

**A little background:**

I am writing some very basic error handling for a macro that runs some pretty important company processes.

As nobody here at work is a true software engineer, the time we can devote to writing error handling routines is not significant.

Anyway, there's a routine that runs every night on a schedule and it processes several reports (in excel) that were completed throughout the day. This routine runs fine for the most part, but since it occurs in the background I have no way of knowing if something went wrong during the previous night's update unless I check on it every morning.

So the error handling I have in place at the moment is that on error - any error - it sends me an email saying "hey something went wrong" (or something to that effect). This lets me aware of any intermittent errors that pop up before the other departments see them, without having to "helicopter parent" the system, so to speak.

**My question is:**
I have this fantasy in my head that within the email, it would have the text of the line where the error occurred. It's not the biggest deal not to have this, but it would speed up the process of troubleshooting a little bit.

Googling this is proving a little frustrating... does anyone know if this is possible, and how I would go about doing this?

Comment: I don't know about sending the actual line but you could send yourself the line number and just look at it in your own copy of the macro.

Comment: I would love to do this but don't know how to get that.

Comment: You can add line numbers to your code and use Erl to get the line number. See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send yourself a line number so that you could find the offending line
The line numbers can be added easily using Mz-Tools

```
Sub ErrTest()
10        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
20        Range("Derp").Select
30        On Error GoTo 0

40        Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
50        Email "example@email.com", _
                Subject:="Error " & Err.Number, _
                Body:="Error " & Err.Number & "(" & Err.Description & ") occured in ErrTest on line " & Erl & "."
End Sub
```

You can retrieve a line of code if you have "Trust access to the VBA project object model" checked in the trust center.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LineCount As Long

    LineCount = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.CountOfLines

    'Print every line in Module1 (lines 1 to LineCount)
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(1, LineCount)
End Sub
```

This could be used to email yourself the specific line number. You would have to add line numbers to every line of code and use Erl in order for this to work.

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work. There are too many lines to add the numbers manually, and Mz-Tools isn't compatible with 64-bit office.

Comment: I develop in 32-bit office because there are so many tools that can't be used in the 64-bit version. I do have to support the 64-bit version though. You could export your modules to text files write another program to add line numbers and then import them back in although that is a pretty hackish solution..

Comment: @M.Banerjee BTW, NOtepadd++ has the option/plugin TextFX that will insert line numbers

Comment: I don't necessarily want to go the line number route because it's not built into VBA. I can add them in manually/with notepad++ once, but every time I want to make a change to the code, it's another hassle I'd have to deal with. Is there a way to just copy the text of the offending line?

Comment: Looking all over and not seeing anything helpful.  Interesting problem though, will keep lookin.

Comment: The second example code I have there will allow you to copy the line but everything I'm aware of that does this in VBA is going to require line numbers.